# Should you check for a null string if you are checking it against a regex?

Tags: c#, exception, arguments

I have the following method:

```
public void Foo(string email)
{
    if (!EmailRegex.IsMatch(email)) throw new InvalidEmailException(...);

    // etc ...
}
```

---

Given that the method would already say that a null email address is invalid, do I really need to test for a null argument as well?

It just seems a bit redundant, even though it would give more clarity to the problem -- that is, no value was passed in vs the value does not match the proper convention.

**This might be a bit subjective, so I'm looking for a more authoritative rule, perhaps some guidance by some MSDN documentation.**

Comment: Maybe design-by-contract programming will give you answer? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: If method has a null check then it would be redundant unless you want to throw different exception (e.g. ArgumentNullException) instead of InvalidEmailException.